# Print out of a data file in c is completely wrong

Tags: c, file, io, fopen

I am trying to get a file from a directory and keep it in memory, the goal is to then copy information from the file structure by structure into a tmp file, do some editing, then save the new info in a new data file. All i'm trying to do right now is get the file and then print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct hw5_struct {
    char f_name[12];
    char l_name[12];
    int age;
    float height;
}HW5_struct;

void printThisFile( FILE *data );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    const char *fileLocation = argv[1];

    FILE *originalData = fopen( fileLocation, "r" );

    if( access( fileLocation, F_OK ) != -1 )
        printf("The file at %s exists\n", argv[1]);

    printThisFile( originalData );

    //int sizeOfOriginalData = sizeOf( &originalData );

}

void printThisFile( FILE *data ) {
    printf( "printThisFile called\n" );

    int c;
    if ( data ) {
        printf( "printing file contents now:\n" );
        while( ( c = getc( data ) ) != EOF )
            printf("%c", c);
        fclose( data );
    }
}
```

It prints the following:

```
FredHutcheson À@LarryStarchÍÌ¼@LucyLu-FredFlintstone 33£@BarnyRubbleÍÌl@AmandaHelix33³@RobertHenderson7ffÆ@BobbyNLMcÍÌ¼@BettyDurnanJPBFloodProfÀ@
```

I don't really know what it is supposed to look like exactly, but its definitely not that.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).....). Then **use the debugger** `gdb`; use also some octal or hexa dump utility to understand the file's content, e.g. [od](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html)

Comment: At a first glance, your output looks compatible with your implicit file format.

Comment: Using `access()` like that is mostly pointless.  If you're going to use it, call it before you call `fopen()`, but you shouldn't bother.  You should check that the file was opened in the function that calls `fopen()`, not the called function.  If you don't know what's meant to be in the data file, how are we going to be able to help?  Maybe you need to show the program that wrote say those records to the file.  You used `fwrite()`, didn't you?  Why not use `fread()` to read the records back?

Answer (score 1):

This would make sense if whatever wrote that file was writing binary versions of `hw5_struct`

If that's the case you need to load the file by doing the corresponding binary read

`FILE *originalData = fopen( fileLocation, "rb" );`

`HW5_struct tempStruct;`

`fread ( &tempStruct, sizeof(hw5_struct),1, data);`

You can then pick it apart by printing the bits.

`printf("%s %s %d %f\n", tempStruct.f_name, tempStruct.l_name,tempStruct.age, tempStruct.height);`

Your current read code will only work with a text file.

Comment: I am very new to C and this helped a lot and fixed my issue thank you!

Comment: Good stuff.  C is tricky.  A great base but most of this weirdness goes away (or at least changes a bit!) when you change to more contemporary languages.  Feel free to accept the answer and give the reputation I crave :)